# How to get the elements out of a set in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a very large dataframe whose column values are all sets, `set()`. Like for example:

```
index    val1         val2
    1    {reg, sgs}   {dsggs, sgsg}
    2    {34, gsg}    {sdg, 23}
```

I want to get only their elements or values. What is the easiest way of doing it?

```
  index    val1       val2
      1    reg, sgs   dsggs, sgsg
      2    34, gsg    sdg, 23
```

Thanks

Comment: The elements as in a string?

Comment: `pd.Series.str.join(', ')`?

Comment: Whats the end-goal here? is it for cosmetic purposes or do you need to do some analysis?

Comment: @DaniMesejo some of them have strings other numbers. For me I can get them as string.

Comment: @Ch3steR I have 156 columns, so i have to use it directly on the whole dataframe, not column by column..

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.applymap` to apply a function to every value in every column.

```
import pandas as pd


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'val1': [{'reg', 'sgs'}, {34, 'gsg'}],
        'val2': [{'dsggs', 'sgsg'}, {'sdg', 23}],
    })
    print(df.applymap(lambda s: ", ".join(map(str, s))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
       val1         val2
0  reg, sgs  dsggs, sgsg
1   gsg, 34      sdg, 23
```

Comment: What error do you get? All I've assumed is that all your data are iterable (singleton sets are no issue).